# Subfolders for MVC Views

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

My regular url layout looks like this:

`http://localhost:1337/Site1`

`http://localhost:1337/Site2`

`http://localhost:1337/Site3`

Now I want to create the administration in a separate sub-folder in the /Views/ directory. So the URLs should look like:

`http://localhost:1337/Administration/AdminSite1`
`http://localhost:1337/Administration/AdminSite2`
`http://localhost:1337/Administration/AdminSite3`

This apparently doesn't work with just creating a subfolder in the Views directory.

This is what my views folder looks like:

`/Views/Site1/Index.cshtml`

`/Views/Site2/Index.cshtml`

`/Views/Site3/Index.cshtml`

`/Views/Administration/AdminSite1/Index.cshtml`

`/Views/Administration/AdminSite2/Index.cshtml`

`/Views/Administration/AdminSite3/Index.cshtml`

And the controllers folder accordingly:

`/Controllers/Site1Controller/`

`/Controllers/Site2Controller/`

`/Controllers/Site3Controller/`

`/Controllers/Administration/AdminSite1Controller/`

`/Controllers/Administration/AdminSite2Controller/`

`/Controllers/Administration/AdminSite3Controller/`

How can I handle this?

Comment: In your controller, specify the path to the view on the `return View(path)` statement.

Comment: That's strange... how is your controller named?

Comment: @dema80 I've updated my folder and naming structure in the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's you're actually looking for is `Areas` (an ASP.NET MVC term, sometimes referred to as 'Module' in other MVC frameworks).

See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee671793(v=vs.100).aspx

In short, an `Area` will let you have controllers & views specific to the 'Area', like so:

**Regular structure (default area):**

```
/Models
/Controllers
/Views/[Controller]/[Action].cshtml
```

**'Admin' area (for example):**

```
/Areas/Admin/Models
/Areas/Admin/Controllers/
/Areas/Admin/Views/[Controller]/[Action].cshtml
```

As of routing, you'll usually have to configure it manually by 'registering' areas in `Global.asax`.

Comment: Can I also combine this by adding only one `Administration` area, so it retains its original structure and only changes for the administrators?

Comment: I didn't quite understand your question, you mean that you're having sub-areas as well?

Comment: No, one (default) area for the users: http://localhost/Site1/ (without 'areas') and one for the administrators: http://localhost/areas/administration/AdminSite1/. I've also added an Area `Administration` now, created a folder "AdminSite1" and a Controller "AdminSite1Controller". Which URL do I take now? http://localhost:1337/Administration/AdminSite1/ results in `The type or namespace name 'Optimization' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?)`

Comment: Does your `Global.asax` call `RegisterAllAreas` method on `Application_Start`?

Comment: Yes, it does. I've removed the "Optimization" line from the views web.config, and now it displays a Route Debugger instead of my page

Comment: Does `/Areas/Administration/Views/` contains a `web.config` file? does it contain `<add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>`?

Comment: I see, but what do you mean by "Displays a route debugger"?

Comment: The URL localhost/Administration/AdminSite1/ displays this kind of page (found on google): http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-AIkgFx94dQs/UOXd2_XzPII/AAAAAAAAAz8/vDtj6U9y6-8/s1600/RouteDebuggingResults.jpg

Comment: Please post the content of `/Areas/Administration/AdminSite1AreaRegistration.cs`

Comment: This file is called `AdministrationAreaRegistration` in my project. This is the code: http://pastebin.com/2X6gmrjZ

Comment: According to the `routes` you registered for this area, you need to try: `http://localhost/Administration/Admin1Site/{action}`, add a default `action` for this route or create a new `route`.

Comment: Ah, I managed to get it working! My colleague installed this RouteDebugger reference that is interferring with areas. Thank you  very much, you helped me a lot! :)